# can simulation stop time in simulink be compared with real time?

Tags: simulation, simulink

what time units does this simulation stop time use? is it seconds or msec? or is there any method to measure this time as some time I feel 1 unit of this time is not of constant length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seconds. But Simulink does not run in real-time, so one second of simulation time can a lot less than a second of real-time (if your model runs very fast) or a lot more (if your model runs very slow).

If your model runs "too fast", you can use utilities such as [Simulink Block for Real Time Execution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30953-simulink-block-for-real-time-execution), [Simulink® Real Time Execution](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21908-simulink%C2%AE-real-time-execution), [Real-Time Blockset 7.1 for Simulink](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3175-real-time-blockset-7-1-for-simulink), [Real-Time Pacer for Simulink](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29107-real-time-pacer-for-simulink) or [RTsync Blockset](https://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24975-rtsync-blockset) (there are plenty to choose from) to slow it down to real-time.

Comment: It's not seconds.  It's whatever unit of time is being used by the parameters of the model.  If using typical SI units then it is seconds, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Really? The doc says:
"Stop time: Specify the stop time for the simulation or generated code as a double-precision value, scaled to seconds."

Comment: The doc is describing the typical, and most used situation, but it's not generically correct.  Think of modelling a simple first order system where you specify a time constant in hours (such as say a chemical process).  The simulation stop time is then measured in hours not seconds.  (Of course what I'm describing is only applicable to simulation.  If you are intending to create code from the model to run on a real-time OS then you need to use seconds.)

Comment: OK I guess if every single parameter in your model is scaled to hours or whatever time unit of your choice, then the simulation start/stop time is also in that unit. I think it's a pretty dangerous thing to do though, because it's easy to forget one parameter and get it wrong.

Comment: This is probably more of a philosophical debate.  The doc does seem to imply that time is considered in seconds, but then again because simulink signals are inherently unitless then so is time, really (i.e. feel free to apply your own units, just be consistent).  @PhilGoddard, another caveat (in addition to generating code for real-time OS), though, is if you are simulating Simscape components... which do have units. In that case, I think you would have to consider time as being in seconds.